# Firefox Developer Edition don't load Facebook app

Tags: facebook, firefox, sdk

I've made a simple Facebook Like Button and the code in my website (SDK and the Button). But, for some reason, in Firefox Developer Edition 45.0a2 (Mac OS X) this Button won't load.

I've tested in other browsers like Chrome and Firefox (normal) and both load the Button.

I've tried some fixes in bugzilla, but nothing helps.

My code (SDK - Facebook provides):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't load? what, if anything, is in your browser console or shows an error when examining the requests to and from Facebook?